# Find the set of a given equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

> What is the set $[4]$

but I haven't seen any examples in the text that describe how to approach a question such as this one.

$R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1),(3,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(4,5),(5,4)\}$

I can see that the relation is symmetric, transitive, and reflexive, but not sure how I can use this information for solving the problem.

Any hints that you can provide are appreciated (not looking for a solution).

#### Clarification

Notation $[4]$ means the equivalence class of the element $4$.

Comment: What exactly is $[4]$? I'm unfamiliar with that notation.

Comment: @GFauxPas I too am unfamiliar with that notation (unless we are talking about arrays when programming haha).  I was hoping someone here could explain it to me.

Comment: Is there a footnote or something? The question doesn't appear well-posed (and I'm not sure how the first quoted bit and the relation... relate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $[4]$ is the equivalence class of $4$ in an equivalence relation $R$. It is the set of all elements that are related (or "equivalent") to $4$. To figure this out, just scan the ordered pairs of $R$ and look for the ones that contain a $4$ (or, by the transitivity of $R$, any other element in $[4]$; note that by the reflexivity of $R$, we know that $4 \in [4]$), then add the other element to the set. For example, in this case we have:
$$
[1] = [2] = [3] = \{1,2,3\}
$$

Comment: Ah, I'd only seen $[\![4]\!]_R$ for that.